# Execute SQL Query on Multiple Values Psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis, psycopg2

I'm using *psycopg2* to execute some PostGIS queries but I'm running into issues. Lets say I run a query:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT locations FROM locationtable")
```

This gives me a python variable which is a list of point geometries. Later, say I want to transform them to a different *SRID* I want to be able to do:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ST_Transform(%s,32146)",(locs))
```

But this gives me an error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I realize in this case I could have just combined these two SQL commands, but this is a general problem I have been encountering and want to know if there is a way to pass the list of tuples with *psycopg2* and have the SQL command execute on all the values.

Comment: The error is likely because the first query returns a list  (I guess)and you try to pass that list to a single placeholder.  Does `executemany` work?

Answer (score 1):

It could work with the method [`executemany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) :

```
cursor.executemany("SELECT ST_Transform(%s,32146)",(locs))
```

But `locs` need to be a list of tuples or other sequence type, in example :

```
locs = [(val,) for val in locs]
```

Comment: It didn't give me any errors when executing but for some reason when fetching it says there is nothing to fetch. I saw in the psycopg2 documentation that executemany isn't faster than using execute in a for loop so I decided to just do that because it is easier.

Comment: yes, it may be easier with a loop & execute, in every cases you need a loop, choose what is the more flexible